# Set ignore_above with elastic-spring-data annotations or java api

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I´m trying to set a property called ignore_above.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-above.html

I needed because I hava already data in my index and my Field mapping is like this:

```
@Field(type = FieldType.String, store = true, index = FieldIndex.not_analyzed)
protected String contenido;
```

It´s because of this error:

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Document contains at
>   least one immense term in field="contenido" (whose UTF8 encoding is
>   longer than the max length 32766), all of which were skipped.  Please
>   correct the analyzer to not produce such terms.  The prefix of the
>   first immense term is: '[10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 123, 10,
>   32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 10, 10, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32, 32,
>   32, 34]...', original message: bytes can be at most 32766 in length;
>   got 45805.

What is the best way to face this error? I was reading about this property but I´m not sure it will be the correct way. I don´t need a searchable field ("contenido") but I´ll need to get the string in the future.

Thank you so much!

Comment: were you able to figure this out?

Comment: @animageofmine I wasn`t to be able to fix this. I had to reindex all my documents and set index property to analyzed, Sorry

Comment: I happened to test this out. Basically, ignore_above is a good solution if you don't care about the payload that exceeds 32k bytes or (10k approx if UTF-8) because of underlying limit of Lucene. ignore_above will not index that payload, but still store it. The latest doc (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/ignore-above.html) is worth reading. 

In my case, most of the times, if the payload is above 32k, it is some random garbage from customer. So, ignore_above works fine.